# Cgroup unexpectedly propagates SIGSTOP to the parent

Tags: linux, bash, signals, sudo, cgroups

I have a small script to run a command inside a cgroup that limits CPU time:

```
$ cat cgrun.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <bin>"
    exit 1
fi

sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/cpulimit
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_period_us=1000000 cpulimit
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=100000 cpulimit
sudo cgexec -g cpu:cpulimit sudo -u $USER "$@"
sudo cgdelete cpu:/cpulimit
```

I let the command run: `./cgrun.sh /bin/sleep 10`

Then I send SIGSTOP to the sleep command from another terminal. Somehow at this moment the parent commands, `sudo` and `cgexec` receive this signal as well. Then, I send SIGCONT to the sleep command, which allows sleep to continue.

But at this moment `sudo` and `cgexec` are stopped and never reap the zombie of the sleep process. I don't understand how this can happen? And how can I prevent it? Moreover, I cannot send SIGCONT to `sudo` and `cgexec`, because I'm sending the signals from user, while these commands run as root.

Here is how it looks in htop (some columns omitted):

```
    PID USER S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
1222869 user S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │     │  └─ /bin/bash ./cgrun.sh /bin/sleep 10
1222882 root T  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │     │     └─ sudo cgexec -g cpu:cpulimit sudo -u user /bin/sleep 10
1222884 root T  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │     │        └─ sudo -u desertfox /bin/sleep 10
1222887 user Z  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 │     │           └─ /bin/sleep 10
```

How can create a cgroup in a way that SIGSTOP is not bounced to parent processes?

UPD

If I start the process using systemd-run, I do not observe the same behavior:

```
sudo systemd-run --uid=$USER -t -p CPUQuota=10% sleep 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the "cg tools", I would do it the "hard way" with the shell commands to create the **cpulimit** cgroup (it is a `mkdir`), set the cfs parameters (with `echo` command in the corresponding **cpu.cfs_*** files), create a sub-shell with the `(...)` notation, move it into the cgroup (`echo` command of its pid into the `tasks` file of the cgroup) and execute the requested command in this subshell.

Hence, `cgrun.sh` would look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <bin>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

CGTREE=/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu

sudo -s <<EOF
[ ! -d ${CGTREE}/cpulimit ] && mkdir ${CGTREE}/cpulimit
echo 1000000 > ${CGTREE}/cpulimit/cpu.cfs_period_us
echo 100000 > ${CGTREE}/cpulimit/cpu.cfs_quota_us
EOF

# Sub-shell in background
(
  # Pid of the current sub-shell
  # ($$ would return the pid of the father process)
  MY_PID=$BASHPID

  # Move current process into the cgroup
  sudo sh -c "echo ${MY_PID} > ${CGTREE}/cpulimit/tasks"

  # Run the command with calling user id (it inherits the cgroup)
  exec "$@"

) &

# Wait for the sub-shell
wait $!

# Exit code of the sub-shell
rc=$?

# Delete the cgroup
sudo rmdir ${CGTREE}/cpulimit

# Exit with the return code of the sub-shell
exit $rc
```

Run it (before we get the pid of the current shell to display the process hierarchy in another terminal):

```
$ echo $$
112588
$ ./cgrun.sh /bin/sleep 50
```

This creates the following process hierarchy:

```
$ pstree -p 112588
bash(112588)-+-cgrun.sh(113079)---sleep(113086)
```

Stop the `sleep` process:

```
$ kill -STOP 113086
```

Look at the cgroup to verify that `sleep` command is running into it (its pid is in the `tasks` file) and the CFS parameters are correctly set:

```
$ ls -l /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimit/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cgroup.clone_children
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cgroup.procs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:36 cpu.cfs_period_us
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:36 cpu.cfs_quota_us
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpu.shares
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpu.stat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpu.uclamp.max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpu.uclamp.min
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.stat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage_all
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage_percpu
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage_percpu_sys
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage_percpu_user
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage_sys
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 cpuacct.usage_user
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:38 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.    5 22:36 tasks
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimit/tasks 
113086  # This is the pid of sleep
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimit/cpu.cfs_*
1000000
100000
```

Send SIGCONT signal to the `sleep` process:

```
$ kill -CONT 113086
```

The process finishes and the cgroup is destroyed:

```
$ ls -l /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimit
ls: cannot access '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimit': No such file or directory
```

Get the exit code of the script once it is finished (it is the exit code of the launched command):

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example seems to work properly. Does it indicate that cg tools have some form of bug?

Comment: The cg tools work fine but they are not flexible enough in this use case : two much involved processes...

Comment: @mcsim: I enhanced the script to make it return the exit code of the sub-shell